# Index was outside the bounds of the array in MSCORLIB.DLL

Tags: c#, sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I will be amazed if I find a solution for this, since it is very specific and vague, but I figured I would try.  I'll try to give as much information as humanly possible, since I've been searching for answers for some time now.

I am building a utility in C# which copies records from a file in a library on the i-series/AS400 and builds an encrypted text file with each record from the AS400 as a comma separated string.  In the file, it will have values like filename, fieldvalue1, fieldvalue2, fieldvalue3.  I then take that text file to another PC, and run a C# utility which copies that record into the same file name in a library over there on a different i-series machine.  Unfortunately, I receive the outside bounds of the array exception in some cases, but I cannot determine why.  In the record just prior to the exception, the record looks pretty much the same and it works fine.  My code is below in a nutshell.  I usually don't give up, but I don't expect to ever figure this out.  If someone does, I'll probably sing karaoke tonight.

```
// Select records from AS400 file and write them to text file
Recordset rs = new Recordset();
sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + dataLibrary + "." + fileName;

try
{
    rs.Open(sqlQuery, con);

    while (!rs.EOF)
    {
        int[] fieldLengths;
        fieldLengths = new int[rs.Fields.Count];
        String[] fieldValues;
        fieldValues = new String[rs.Fields.Count];
        String fullString = "";

        for (i = 0; i < rs.Fields.Count; i++)
        {
            fieldLengths[i] += rs.Fields[i].DefinedSize;
            fieldValues[i] += rs.Fields[i].Value;
        }

        fullString = fileName + "," + String.Join(",", fieldValues);
        fullString = Functions.EncryptString(fullString);

        File.AppendAllText(savefile.FileName, fullString + Environment.NewLine);
        rs.MoveNext();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}

cmd.Dispose();
// This gives me a text file of filename, fieldvalue1, fieldvalue2, etc...
// Next, I take the file to another system and run this process:

while ((myString = inputFile.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    int stringLength = myString.Length;
    String[] valuesArray = myString.Split(',');

    for (i = 0; i < valuesArray.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            fileName = valuesArray[0];
            // Create file if it doesn't exist already
            createPhysicalFile(newLibrary, fileName);
            SQLStatement = "INSERT INTO " + newLibrary + "." + fileName + "VALUES(";
        }
        else
        {
            if (i == valuesArray.Length - 1)
            {
                SQLStatement += "@VAL" + i + ")";
            }
            else
            {
                SQLStatement += "@VAL" + i + ", ";
            }
        }
    }

    try
    {
        using (connection)
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

            // Create a new SQL command
            iDB2Command command = new iDB2Command(SQLStatement, connection);

            for (i = 1; i < valuesArray.Length; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL" + i, (valuesArray[i]));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }

            // Just split the array into a string to visually check 
            // differences in the records
            String arraySplit = ConvertStringArrayToString(valuesArray);

            // The query gets executed here.  The command looks something
            // like:  
            // INSERT INTO LIBNAME.FILENAME VALUES(@VAL!, @VAL2, @VAL3, @VAL4)
            // There are actually 320 fields in the file I'm having a problem with, 
            // so it's possible I'm overlooking something.  I have narrowed it down to 
            // field # 316 when the exception occurs, but in both cases 
            // field 316 is blanks (when it works and when it doesn't).
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Here I get the exception out of bounds error in MSCORLIB.DLL. 
        // Some records are added fine, while others cause this exception.
        // I cannot visibly tell any major differences, nor do I see any  
        // errors in the AS400 job log or anything in C# that would lead me 
        // down a certain path.
        String error = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is exactly one reason for the error message you're getting, and it has nothing to do with MSCORLIB (that's just where the exception was raised). It's in your code, and it's because you're reading outside the bounds of one of your arrays, which means that you need to use the debugger to figure out what part of your code is going outside the bounds of `fieldLengths`, `fieldValues`, `rs.Fields`, or `valuesArray`. We can't do that for you, because we don't have the query results from `rs.Open` to use to do so. There are zero other causes for that exception being raised.

Comment: Why don't you start your debugger and step through this code? We can't do it for you while this is the simplest way to discover the exact point where your code fails.

Comment: I'm guessing you aren't checking if the array lengths are non-zero. have you verified which line is throwing the exception with the debugger? step through it line by line until you hit it.

Comment: While you're in there, you might as well yank out that `fieldLengths` variable since it's never used. Or is the problem that it *should* be used somewhere and it isn't?

Comment: Why are your arrays 0-indexed in some places but 1-indexed in the loop that causes you grief?

Comment: That's what I have been chasing for a week.  The fact that this exception occurs on the command.ExecuteNonQuery(), and not with any dealings of the recordset or the arrays, and the the same number of values are passed with one that works and one that doesn't, it leads me to believe there is something deeper going on at the AS400 field level.  As a matter of fact, if Have manually set parameters near the end to have the value of 0 instead of blanks, and it allowed the record to be written just fine.

Comment: mustaccio, I agree, it's probably not the best way.  I'm still in a proof of concept mode.  Basically, the first element of the array is the file name so that the utility will know what file to put the record into on the destination machine.  It's intentionally starting with the 2nd element of the array to begin the actual record data.

Comment: It looks to me like all the indexers in this block are properly bounded, and I don't see a way for the number of parameter values to differ from the number of placeholders. What is the implementation of `ConvertStringArrayToString`? To verify it is the `ExecuteNonQuery` call could you wrap just that line in another `try` and log the query and values on exception? Also, how did you narrow it down to field 316?

Comment: Another edge case that jumps out is if `valuesArray` is empty, it looks like `SQLStatement` will maintain it's value across iterations.

Comment: Hi Ryachza, the ConvertStringArrayToString is just a routine I wrote to put an array into a string, so that I could copy the contents to notepad and compare a working one with a non-working one.  It can be safely removed.  I added another try statement, which also went into the same exception.

Comment: @user1420914 You added the `try`, and you logged the `SQLStatement` and `valuesArray`? I would probably try manually executing the query interleaving the values to prove it works. If it works manually I would try to figure out the difference.

Comment: ValuesArray is certainly not empty.  I thought at first this was happening only when element 5 had the value of 101, and this field is packed on the AS400, but then I saw another case where it happened as well.  It feels like maybe a packed field issue or something.  I've seen some things online about having to send the data type in the call, but haven't found a clear answer.

Comment: @user1420914 Aren't all your data types strings? I don't see any deserialization. But manually putting the static SQL string together and running it might indicate something. If that works, perhaps try eliminating the parameterization as a variable and use full dynamic SQL (don't keep it that way, but just to debug).

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I will try that.  It will take some time, as there are 320 fields.  :)

Comment: @user1420914 Since they're already comman separated, you should be able to just paste the record into an `INSERT` statement and do like a find and replace commas with quote-comma-quote, then touch up any values that are funny.

Comment: Is there any reason you are converting the file from a database file to a CSV, and then back to a database file on another system rather than just FTP the file or a savefile containing the file from the source system to the target system? You could even use SFTP, or maybe even better `SAVRSTOBJ`

Comment: Hi jmark.  It's complicated.  A lot of time is wasted waiting for clients to respond with the stuff we need, while at the same time they are annoyed at us for not finishing their projects on time.  The idea is to gather specific setup data from their system and import it into our system, so that we can test against data that matches theirs as close as possible.  Not all clients have the same files, so I'm trying to come up with a solution that will work for all.

Comment: @user1420914 Which AS/400 driver are you using? The iSeries driver included with IBM System i Access for Windows?

Comment: Yes, I'm using:  IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries;

Comment: @user1420914 I suspect the issue might be related to the `try`/`catch` surrounding `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VAL" + i, (valuesArray[i]));`, the iSeries driver was always *really* weird when I worked with it last, and reported things pretty peculiarly. Also, at one point, I remember that parameterized queries in ADO.NET with that driver required use of `?` instead of parameter names, the order was the only thing important, this sounds like it might be related to your issue, I suspect you're not providing enough fields.

Comment: Yeah, I may just have to go back to the drawing board.  Never had anything like this happen to me before.  Usually nothing works at all and I'd be able to figure out the root cause, but when it adds 1000 records to the file and leaves out 5 of them randomly, I'm pretty perplexed.  I'll sleep on it, then think about alternatives tomorrow.  :)

Comment: @user1420914 When I worked with an AS/400 it came down to that type of issue, the AS/400 expects that if you supply 15 parameter placeholders, you have 15 parameters and values. If any get forgotten for whatever reason, it will *almost certainly* throw this specific error, because parameters are simply indexed and not named. (If you specify `@Param1, @Param2`, but `Parameters.Add` in order of `@Param2` then `@Param1`, the value for `@Param1` in the query becomes that of `@Param2`, and `@Param2` gets filled with the `@Param1` value.)

Comment: FTP ought to work for any file. you just have to tell which file to retrieve. An other option is to use `CPYTOSTMF` and `CPYFRMSTMF`. This can produce a CSV in the IFS which can be either ftp'd or accessed via a mapped drive. If you are amenable to a non-windows solution, there are several simpler options.

Comment: oh yeah, FTP is a breeze.  But we are talking about 1500 different files, and you can't FTP the entire library due to sensitive data & security restraints.  I did all of this manually once upon a time, and it took about 4 days just to get the data separated to a point that I could send it back home.  I am hoping to make the process more automated and human proof.  I suppose if it comes down to it, I can live with it as it is since this error is only happening on 1 file so far....I just hate errors that I can't find an explanation to.

Comment: I just build the ftp script dynamically

Comment: Hi Jmark, is it possible to build an FTP script that says that if a record in the file contains a certain value in a certain field, to exclude that record from the save?  If so, I might look at doing it that way instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, I found this happening one a smaller file in the system and was able to figure out what going on, after painstaking research into the code and the net.  Basically, the file file has numeric fields on the i-series.  Somehow, the records were written to the file on the original system with null values in the numeric fields instead of numeric values.  When storing the original records, I had to do this calculation:

```
String fieldType = rs.Fields[i].Type.ToString();
object objValue = rs.Fields[i].Value;
if (fieldType == "adNumeric" && objValue is DBNull)
{
  fieldValues[i] += "0";
}
else
{
  fieldValues[i] += rs.Fields[i].Value;
}
```

After this, if null values were found in one of the numeric fields, it just put "0" in it's place so that when writing to the new machine, it would put a valid numeric character in there and continue on writing the rest of the values.  Thanks for all the advice and moral support.  :)